# DataExporter not working for filtered dataTable in Primefaces 3.2

Tags: jsf

In my application I am using global filter for searching the records in Primefaces DataTable and I have applied DataExporter on the same DataTable.

When I Search any record and go for export, it return me a complete list of data instead of filtered list.

My development environment is:
java 6.0, Primefaces 3.2, JSF2.1, GlassFish Server 3.1.2, Netbeans 7.1.1

---

Enlisted below my dataTable and dataExporter code.

My dataTable code is::

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{personnelController.allItems}" 
                                     emptyMessage="#{bundle.PersonnelEmpty}"
                                     selectionMode="single"
                                     dblClickSelect="false"
                                     var="item"
                                     id="tbl"
                                     rowKey="#`enter code here`{item.id}"
                                     sortBy="#{item.lastName}"
                                     sortOrder="ascending"
                                     widgetVar="itemTable"
                                     paginator="true"
                                     paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                     paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                                     currentPageReportTemplate="Page {currentPage} of {totalPages}"
                                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                                     rows="10"
                                     >
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                <p:outputPanel>  
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.GlobalFilterPrompt}" />  
                                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" 
                                                 onkeyup="itemTable.filter()" 
                                                 style="width:150px;" 
                                                 />  
                                    <p:watermark for="globalFilter" value="#{bundle.GlobalFilterWatermark}" />
                                </p:outputPanel>  
                            </f:facet>  
                            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{personnelController.onRowSelectNavigate}" /> 

                            <p:column 
                                sortBy="#{item.lastName}"
                                filterBy="#{item.lastName}"
                                filterStyle="display: none;"
                                >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.PersonnelTitle_lastName}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.lastName}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column 
                                sortBy="#{item.firstName}"
                                filterBy="#{item.firstName}"
                                filterStyle="display: none;" 
                                >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.PersonnelTitle_firstName}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.firstName}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column 
                                sortBy="#{item.location.name}"
                                filterBy="#{item.location.name}"
                                filterStyle="display: none;"
                                >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.PersonnelTitle_locations}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.location.name}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column 
                                sortBy="#{item.department.name}"
                                filterBy="#{item.department.name}"  
                                filterStyle="display: none;"
                                >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.PersonnelTitle_departments}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.department.name}"/>
                            </p:column>

                        </p:dataTable>
```

I am exporting table data from outside the dataTable as::

```
 <h:commandLink>  
      <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:excel.png']}" />  
      <p:dataExporter type="xls" target=":personnel:tbl" fileName="personnel" />  
 </h:commandLink>
```

Please suggest me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I'm using dataexporter with filtered datatable and it exports filtered data only. Can you post your code?

Comment: see my updated answer, I hope this can solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

This is my example of a usertable:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{myBean.users}" var="usr" rowKey="#{usr.username}" widgetVar="usrwv">
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <p:outputPanel>  
                 <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
                 <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="usrwv.filter()" style="width:150px" />  
            </p:outputPanel>  
        </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="Username" sortBy="#{usr.username}" filterBy="#{usr.username}">
               <f:facet name="header">  
                     Username
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{usr.username}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Role" sortBy="#{usr.role}" filterBy="#{usr.role}">
                <f:facet name="header">  
                     Role
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{usr.role}"/>
        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:commandLink>  
                     <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/excel.ico" title="myExcel"/>
                     <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="table" fileName="all_users"/>  
                </h:commandLink>
        </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

Also you are putting the exporter and the datatable in two different forms. Try putting them in the same form. This should work.

Comment: Thanks Fareed !!

By putting DataTable and DataExporter in a single form I have got the desired result :)

Answer (score 0):

In the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.10.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
   <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
   <version>5.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And replace:

```
<h:commandLink>  
      <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:excel.png']}" />  
      <p:dataExporter type="xls" target=":personnel:tbl" fileName="personnel" />  
 </h:commandLink>

 <h:commandLink>  
      <h:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:excel.png']}" />  
      <p:dataExporter type="xls" target=":personnel:tbl" fileName="personnel" />  
 </h:commandLink>
```